# What throttles the fwrite() calls to a full disk on linux?

Tags: c, linux

It appears that if my program attempts to write to a full file system it it will initially error with 'No space left on device' nearly instantly, but if I leave it running for a minute or so it slows down by a couple orders of magnitude.

Note this is a minimum test case, this behaviour was first noticed in a Java logging framework, hence the small (512 byte) output chunks and a lot of them.

`main.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


long microTime() {
    struct timeval time;
    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);

    return time.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 + time.tv_usec;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *payload ;
    payload = (char *)malloc(512 * sizeof(char));

    if (payload == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to alloc memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "a+");

    printf("opened [%s]\n", argv[1]);

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open [%s]\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (;;) {
        int batchSize = 100000;
        bool errored = false;
        long runStart = microTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i ++) {
            size_t result = fwrite(payload, 512 * sizeof(char), 1, fp);
            if (result == 0 && !errored) {
                perror("Failed to write to disk");
                errored = true;
            }

        }
        long runEnd = microTime();
        printf("total elapsed %dms\n", (int)(runEnd - runStart) / 1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(please excuse my C, this is probably the first C program I've written in nearly 20 years)

Running:

`gcc -std=c99 main.c && ./a.out /path/to/somewhere/file1.bin`

**Warning this program will fill your disk partition**

output:

```
total elapsed 42ms
total elapsed 105ms
total elapsed 104ms
total elapsed 125ms
... skip until the disk fills
Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
total elapsed 104ms
Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
total elapsed 76ms
Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
total elapsed 84ms
Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
... then skip a little more about one minute
total elapsed 8096ms
Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
total elapsed 43245ms
Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
total elapsed 48670ms
Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
total elapsed 45929ms
Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
```

My expectation is that this program would run for ever with a fairly low constant time to write to disk.

I've run this on a local centos 6.4 vagrant box, an amazon linux and an ubuntu 14.04 ec2 boxes with exactly the same results. Interestingly it doesn't seem to happen on OSX 10.9.5 attempting to fill a disk image.

So my question is really, what is causing this apparent throttling?

update: Run with strace -t -T

```
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000011>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000011>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000066>
10:27:38 dup(2)                         = 4 <0.000006>
10:27:38 fcntl(4, F_GETFL)              = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE) <0.000011>
10:27:38 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
10:27:38 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa8e97f2000 <0.000009>
10:27:38 lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)          = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek) <0.000005>
10:27:38 write(4, "Failed to write to disk: No spac"..., 49Failed to write to disk: No space left on device
) = 49 <0.000006>
10:27:38 close(4)                       = 0 <0.000006>
10:27:38 munmap(0x7fa8e97f2000, 4096)   = 0 <0.000015>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000026>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000017>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000016>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000016>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000015>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000016>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000015>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000015>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000016>
10:27:38 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.000016>

... skipping to the end
10:30:02 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.005747>
10:30:02 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.005231>
10:30:02 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.005496>
10:30:02 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.005870>
10:30:02 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.005823>
10:30:02 write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device) <0.005841>
```

not the call times to `write()` go from ~0.00001s => ~0.005s by the end of the run.

[The full run.log is 250mb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5427964/so/28021708/run.log)

update 2: Adding CPU usage detail for the various phases:

Staring the run, ie filling the disk

```
top - 11:00:56 up  2:52,  2 users,  load average: 1.79, 0.99, 0.48
Tasks:  75 total,   3 running,  72 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.3%us, 71.8%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa, 14.6%hi,  6.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    603764k total,   561868k used,    41896k free,   134976k buffers
Swap:  1254392k total,        0k used,  1254392k free,   359020k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 9861 vagrant   20   0  4056  500  412 R 54.5  0.1   0:01.88 a.out
  766 root      20   0     0    0    0 R 36.9  0.0   0:28.51 flush-8:0
   28 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  5.6  0.0   0:05.14 kswapd0
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  2.3  0.0   4:51.07 kblockd/0
```

Disk full, fast erroring

```
top - 11:01:11 up  2:52,  2 users,  load average: 1.68, 1.01, 0.49
Tasks:  75 total,   2 running,  73 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  9.0%us, 91.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    603764k total,   555424k used,    48340k free,   134976k buffers
Swap:  1254392k total,        0k used,  1254392k free,   352224k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 9861 vagrant   20   0  4056  552  464 R 99.5  0.1   0:12.91 a.out
  988 root      20   0  215m 1572  860 S  0.3  0.3   0:05.05 VBoxService
    1 root      20   0 19228 1348 1072 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.24 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
```

Slow erroring

```
top - 11:03:03 up  2:54,  2 users,  load average: 1.63, 1.14, 0.59
Tasks:  74 total,   3 running,  71 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.4%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 98.8%wa,  0.4%hi,  0.4%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    603764k total,   555284k used,    48480k free,   134976k buffers
Swap:  1254392k total,        0k used,  1254392k free,   352308k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  216 root      20   0     0    0    0 R  3.7  0.0   4:50.72 jbd2/sda1-8
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 R  3.3  0.0   4:53.04 kblockd/0
 9861 vagrant   20   0  4056  552  464 D  1.3  0.1   1:17.47 a.out
    1 root      20   0 19228 1348 1072 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.24 init
```

Comment: My guess is that it's searching for space in the filesystem, and this is slow when the filesystem is full.

Comment: How does the test perform when exchanging the 2nd and 3rd parameter to `fwrite()`?

Comment: Gareth: can you please run your code under `strace`  and post the output? Tracking time (`-t`, `-T` etc. might help a lot).

Comment: but it manages to return 'No space left on device' for about a minute and then slows down. At which point it's already found out that the disk is full quite a few times (several million times)

Comment: @cnicutar will do ... will take a wee while

Comment: I had a theory that this could be stdio being clever and buffering your output and you end up swapping. But that doesn't sound like standard behavior. I tested on Centos 6.5 and the program does nothing strange. It has now been running for a few minutes with 11-12ms per call and doesn't get throttled. And it doesn't eat more memory or anything like that. I would suspect this is a strange artifact of ec2 rather than Centos.

Comment: @cnicutar have updated the question with the strace output

Comment: The strace seems to indicate that this is something happening on the operating system level. I'm not aware of any mechanism in linux that will throttle disk I/O even on errors. Can you see if your system is spending time doing something else at the same time? Like spinning in syslog spamming your logs with "please don't fill the disk or we'll charge your credit card with the national debt of small country" or something. Does dmesg get filled with messages?

Comment: @Gareth, which file system are you using? A quick search indicates that at least XFS can do funny things with throttling when in `ENOSPC` condition.

Comment: Isn't this plain CPU throttling? What does top look like when it starts to go slowly? (Steal time%?)

Comment: @Art this is my issue... I haven't ever heard of anything like this before ... wierd isn't it?

Comment: @art nothing in dmesg on my vagrant box, but then it's disk gets filled, will have to boot up another box with a spare partition.

Comment: @Mat have adding CPU usage from top during the run, interesting it shows that the during the 'slow error' phase `kblockd` and `jbd2` are active.

Comment: Missing the top line with the global stats, including steal time.

Comment: @mat sorry, have added in the top lines

Comment: @Art _I'm not aware of any mechanism in linux that will throttle disk I/O even on errors_ - prepare to be surprised then, read up on vm.dirty_ratio.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin vm_dirty.ratio has nothing to do with this. Since the file system is full we're not producing any dirty pages. `write` returning an error pretty clearly indicates that nothing got queued to the disk or got dirtied in the buffer cache. Anything else would have been a bug in the kernel. And I shouldn't have "disk I/O", I meant "filesystem I/O". Minor difference.

Comment: have just rerun this on an Amazon linux ec2 instance, filling a separate 1 gb parition and there is no spam in any /var/log/* file

Comment: @GarethDavis Did the smaller partition change the behavior or do you still see the writing process block on errors?

Comment: @Art I guess `write` has to block untill `vm.dirty_ratio` threshold is restored. By the time the treshold has restored the filesystem state may have changed and more space is available.

Answer (score 4):

You may be observing the effects of Linux virtual memory when `write` system calls block and become synchronous. This is because your application continuously generates data to be written to disk and the disk cannot store the data as fast.

Alternatively, the background flush out kicks in sometime after the disk was filled, so that `write` syscalls compete for a access with the kernel flush out thread to the filesystem internal structures, so that it takes longer to return `ENOSPC`.

See [Better Linux Disk Caching & Performance with vm.dirty_ratio & vm.dirty_background_ratio](https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/):

> vm.dirty_background_ratio is the percentage of system memory that can be filled with “dirty” pages — memory pages that still need to be written to disk — before the pdflush/flush/kdmflush background processes kick in to write it to disk. My example is 10%, so if my virtual server has 32 GB of memory that’s 3.2 GB of data that can be sitting in RAM before something is done.
>
> vm.dirty_ratio is the absolute maximum amount of system memory that can be filled with dirty pages before everything must get committed to disk. **When the system gets to this point all new I/O blocks until dirty pages have been written to disk. This is often the source of long I/O pauses**, but is a safeguard against too much data being cached unsafely in memory.

Comment: surely the writes shouldn't make it as far as a cache as they are correctly rejected because the disk is full.

Comment: @GarethDavis I guess `write` has to block untill `vm.dirty_ratio` threshold is restored. By the time the treshold has restored the filesystem state may have changed and more space is available.

Comment: is there a way I can test this theory? so if I change vm. dirty_background_ratio to be say 1, should the 'slow erroring' happen sooner?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin If it was a dirty page limit, it would hit before we run out of space, not 35 seconds later. If you look at the log, the filesystem fills up at 10:27:38 and the time spent in each failed `write` call doesn't get high until 10:28:13.

Comment: @Art I added an alternative hypotheses.

Comment: have just rerun first using vm.dirty_background_ratio set to 1 and the time from running out of space to slowing down is ~35 seconds (in vagrant box) I set the vm.dirty_background_ratio to 50 and the same time was more or less the same (I was using stopwatch on my phone not exactly hires timing).

Comment: @GarethDavis I would try printing the current values of the thresholds before writes.